# While running a application using spark-submit in Apache Spark, gave WARN message

Tags: hadoop, ssh, apache-spark, pyspark, python-3.3

I have configured Apache Spark standalone cluster into two Ubuntu 14.04 VMs. One of the VMs i.e. Master and the other one i.e. Worker,both are connected with password less ssh described [here](http://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-using-ssh-keygen-in-5-easy-steps/).

After that from the Master, I have started master as well as worker by the following command from the spark home directory -

```
sbin/start-all.sh
```

Then I run the following command from Master as well as Woker VMs.

```
jps
```

It shows in Master VM-

```
6047 jps
6048 Master
```

And into Worker VM-

```
6046 jps
6045 Worker
```

It seemed that the Master and Worker is running properly and also in Web UI, there is no error occured.
But when I am trying to run an application using the following command-

```
spark-1.6.0/bin/spark-submit spark.py
```

It gives WARN message in console that-

```
TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

Here is my test application-

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import  SQLContext
conf =SparkConf().setMaster('spark://SparkMaster:7077').setAppName("My_App")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
SQLCtx = SQLContext(sc)
list_of_list = sc.textFile("ver1_sample.csv").map(lambda line: line.split(",")).collect()
print("type_of_list_of_list===========",type(list_of_list), list_of_list)
```

As I am new to Apache Spark. Please help.

Comment: Do you see the workers listed on the Spark Web UI? if yes trying adding `--master` to the `spark-submit` command to ensure that you are submitting your job to right Spark Master.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be with the resource (memory/cores) availability. By default spark takes default from spark-defaults.conf.

Try using

```
bin/spark-submit --executor-memory 1g
```

Comment: I have done with the above command but still it is giving the same WARN message as I mentioned above

Comment: When I am trying to run the application by creating the worker in the same server where the master exists, the application have executed successfully. The WARN message is giving only when the Master and Worker are separated. Both VMs are ec2 instances. Is there any network issues regarding the WARN message? @Atul Soman